# My pc stuck at blinking underscore

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bsod

While I was using my pc suddenly a bsod stating inaccessible Boot drive came and my pc restarted and came to a black screen with blinking under score

I then gone to the bios and saw whether hdd was detected and checked boot options and everything was correct

I then tried to install a fresh windows 7 using bootable usb but during setup it states no drives found

What should I do now , what must have happen pls help me ...

Comment: Your drive has failed.

Comment: So my hdd is dead ?

Comment: Can i recover my files

Comment: How to solve this

Comment: I would start by buying a new harddrive/SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk is dead - buy a new one and install a fresh Windows version.

You may install the bad disk as the second disk inside the computer
and see if it's detected in the Device Manager
(or put it in a case and use as external disk).

If it is detected, you might try some of the following data recovery
programs:

1. [MiniTool Power Data Recovery](http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/) (Free Edition)
   I count it as the best of its kind.
   The free version has a limit of 1GB of recovered data.
2. [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)
3. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
4. [PC Inspector File Recovery](http://www.pcinspector.de/Default.htm?language=1)
5. [Puran File Recovery](http://www.puransoftware.com/File-Recovery.html)

A weird-sounding method to resuscitate a rotating disk for a short
while is to wrap it in plastic and with some humidity-sponging
material (even rice) and put it in the deep-freeze for an hour.

Otherwise, if recovering the lost data is worth paying for,
you could use a professional company specializing in data-recovery